# Javascript replace() only once per occurrence

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace

I'm replacing all enter hits to HTML `<br>` tags by replacing them globally. I'm using below code line for that.

Javascript Code:

```
var text = document.getElementById('text_input').value.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
```

HTML Code

```
<textarea placeholder="Write New.." id="text_input" name="text_input" class="text_input" spellcheck="true" ></textarea>
```

so if I hit enter twice or more it replaces all enter hits to HTML `<br>` tags. But I want to replace **one `<br>` tag per line**.

Comment: Can you add some HTML pls mate

Comment: @AdamJeffers I have added my HTML code line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to replace consecutive matches, use the `+` symbol in your regex:

```
var text = document.getElementById('text_input').value.replace(/\n+/g, "<br />");
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!